# Having the visibility of IK/FK controls being driven by the IK/FK switch?

Tags: animation, rigging

I'd like some help making some slight tweaks and mods to this dank free BodyMechanic rig I found on blend swap;
https://www.blendswap.com/blend/19110
Basically I think it would be super useful to have it so that the visibility of the IK/FK controls are driven by the IK/FK switch. For example if your Left Hand is in FK, the IK controls automatically get hidden. Then if I switch to IK, the FK controls for that arm are hidden and the IK controls appear.
It would be a huge time saver and make the use of this rig that much more streamlined.
I don't know how that can be done, if anyone out there has an idea, your help would be much appreciated.
Thanks and a big ups to Vinchau, the dude who created the rig in the first place :D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hover on the IK_FK slider > right mouse button > copy as new driver.

Then select a bone of the IK controllers, go to the outliner, enable the visibility icon (screen shape), press dot in the numpad to highlight the selected bone, right click on the visibility icon and choose paste driver.

Repeat for the other IK bones.

Then, for the FK bones you will have to change the driver expression: paste the same on one of the control bones, edit driver and change it from average value to scripted expression and type in "1-IK_FK".

Then copy this new driver and paste it on the others FK bones.

Note that both IK and FK layers have to be permanently turned on (I've tried to work on layers visibility, but it doesn't work, I don't know why).

For values different from 0.0 and 1.0 both bone chains are visible (which I think is useful).

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! 
That did exactly what I wanted, thanks very much!